# What is the scope of an include within an include?

Tags: c++, include

I'm not exactly certain what happens but take the following:

```
class A{

}
```

-

```
class B{
 #include "A.h"
}
```

-

```
class C{
 #include "B.h"
}
```

Now if I were to code in class C does it mean class A is also automatically included as well? From what I understand is that #include basically copies the entire file right on the spot.

Can anyone elaborate on this?

I'm trying to use class forwarding as much  as I can. But sometimes I simply can not.

Edit:

The classes above are not in the same file. Imagine them separated.

Edit II:
Let me put it into more context.

Lets say I'm creating a new class that includes class B, but then I declare a variable of type A. This seems to compile even though I never included A to the class. Is this just how it goes in C++?

Comment: The structure of your files is not clear.

Comment: I don't follow. Please elaborate

Comment: @Sidar it's not clear what A.h and B.h are.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Assuming each header contains the class of the same name is a pretty safe bet, isn't it?

Comment: @delnan that's what I assumed in my answer :)...

Comment: I don't know if I'm tired, or just not following this. But I really don't get what you are trying to point out =(

Comment: @delnan he was talking about kirill kobolevs comment

Comment: @delnan because the op asked Kiril to elaborate...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would basically declare a **nested class** called A inside class `B`.

Cases where `include` directives should be anywhere else other than the top of the file are very rare, and usually have completely different purpose than what you have.

If I understood your file hierarchy correctly, it's equivalent to:

```
//A.h
class A{

};

//B.h
class B{
  class A{

  };
};

//C.h
class C{
  class B{
    class A{

    };
  };
};
```

Comment: I gave my question more context. Could you respond to it?

Comment: @Sidar the answer still holds. If you have an `A` as a pointer, you need to include the header, before the class defintion, not inside it. If you have a member `A*` or `A&`, a forward declaration is enough.

Comment: It's not exactly what I was asking. But I'm tired and frankly can't care at the moment. Have your free approval =P

Comment: @Sidar I did say that if you have an object as member, you need to include. *That* is how C++ works. IDK what else you're asking.

Comment: My question is that while I have an object of A in C but only included B it still compiles;  Why is this? Is it because the contents of A are copied into B and therefor are available for C?

Comment: It seems so sketchy. It feels like it isn't clean at all like this. Oh well. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, the preprocessor just copies the headers in. Think of it like a long macro if you will.

Answer (score 1):

A `#include` directive simply tells the compiler to pretend that the text in the named file had been written where the `#include` directive occurs. It has nothing to do with scopes, syntax, or anything else. It's simply text.

Without seeing the contents of A.h and B.h it's impossible to say anything more about what the effects of those `#include` directives are.

Comment: I'm seriously confused now, they are just simple classes that include another. I'm not sure what to show. Could you extrapolate on your answer then ? What factors are involved?

Comment: @Sidar: #include is like a copy-and-paste operation. The text in the given file is pasted exactly where the #include is.

Comment: @NicolBolas

I get that, but is this the reason why A becomes visible in C?

Comment: So in your original message (as edited), the first block is A.h, the second is B.h, and the third is where the question arises. @Luchian gave you the answer, but to elaborate a bit: #include "B.h" reads in the contents of B.h, which includes #include "A.h"; that include directive reads in the contents of A.h, which is why A goes in there.

Comment: When the effects of the preprocessor get confusing, it helps to look at what it's doing. You compiler has a command-line switch to generate preprocessed output (the switch is probably -E). Don't do anything complicated --- just your original example, and look at what the preprocessor did to it.